# Selenium: How can I navigate back to parent window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running below java code for switching windows and getting error message, Kindly suggest something.

```
Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
    Set<String>set=Driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> It=set.iterator();
    String PId=It.next();
    String CId=It.next();
    Driver.switchTo().window(CId);


    Driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");/* Here again I want to come back to parent window and perform some action */
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this java documentation link for the list of available switchTo options:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html

In your case, you may need to save the window handle before switching and then use it later to switch back to original window.

```
String originalWindow = Driver.getWindowHandle();
Driver.switchTo().window(CId);
//Operations on new window here
Driver.switchTo().window(originalWindow);
//Operations on original window here
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with windows, it has to do with switching to IFRAMEs and back.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was of the opinion that it'll switch to default window as well. Just tested it out and it doesn't work. I'll update my answer.